# Prediction labels are off - KERAS / Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, image-classification

I am using KERAS/TF to make an image classifier with transfer learning including pre-trained model weights. The image dataset is split in 80/10/10. Categories are string labels ranging from 1 - 80.

For pre-processing of the images I am using the ImageDataGenerator and evaluation shows good accuracy on the evaluation set of around 58 percent. However, trying to predict the values on the evaluation set gives an accuracy of around 0.01. I have also tried it on the test set and the results still don't add up.

Does anybody know what is going wrong with predictions?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

```
# Predict values using the test generator
predict = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, 
                                  steps=(validation_generator.n // 32)+1)

# Choose the highest scoring prediction
validate_df['prediction'] = np.argmax(predict, axis=-1)

# assigning label names to the corresponding indexes
labels =  {0 :  '1',  1 :  '2',  2 :  '3',  3 :  '4',  4 :  '5',  5 :  '6',  6 :  '7',  7 :  '8',  8 :  '9',  9 : '10',
          10 : '11', 11 : '12', 12 : '13', 13 : '14', 14 : '15', 15 : '16', 16 : '17', 17 : '18', 18 : '19', 19 : '20', 
          20 : '21', 21 : '22', 22 : '23', 23 : '24', 24 : '25', 25 : '26', 26 : '27', 27 : '28', 28 : '29', 29 : '30', 
          30 : '31', 31 : '32', 32 : '33', 33 : '34', 34 : '35', 35 : '36', 36 : '37', 37 : '38', 38 : '39', 39 : '40', 
          40 : '41', 41 : '42', 42 : '43', 43 : '44', 44 : '45', 45 : '46', 46 : '47', 47 : '48', 48 : '49', 49 : '50', 
          50 : '51', 51 : '52', 52 : '53', 53 : '54', 54 : '55', 55 : '56', 56 : '57', 57 : '58', 58 : '59', 59 : '60', 
          60 : '61', 61 : '62', 62 : '63', 63 : '64', 64 : '65', 65 : '66', 66 : '67', 67 : '68', 68 : '69', 69 : '70', 
          70 : '71', 71 : '72', 72 : '73', 73 : '74', 74 : '75', 75 : '76', 76 : '77', 77 : '78', 78 : '79', 79 : '80'}

# Replace with original lables for comparison
validate_df['prediction'] = validate_df['prediction'].replace(labels)

# Print accuracy score and show output 
print(accuracy_score(validate_df.label, validate_df.prediction))
test_df.head()

0.013067624959163672
img_name    label   prediction
0   train_27493.jpg 17  10
1   train_19980.jpg 60  58
2   train_4348.jpg  71  58
3   train_4141.jpg  11  4
4   train_21555.jpg 36  22
```

Comment: What kind of Architecture do you use? Do you have any Regularization in your model? Did you plotted trainloss against valid loss? What is you validation frequency?

Comment: I am using the InceptionResNetV2 architecture, including a topmodel to classify the images trained on a GPU. Trainloss validation look good, also used earlystopping to prevent overfitting

Comment: I am not completely familar with this architecture, but if it just for classifying an accuracy of 58 % is not a very good accuracy. If you take a look at as example the yolo algorithm which achives 58 % on a much harder task. I just think for the moment your training epochs amount is to low.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I found the error. I forgot to reload the categories back into the train generator
# Convert the predict category back into train_generator.class_indeces
#label_map = dict((v,k) for k,v in train_generator.class_indices.items())
#test_df['prediction'] = test_df['prediction'].replace(label_map)

Answer (score 1):

For the community:

My code was missing the part that converted the values back to the right labels.

After choosing the highest scoring prediction the value has to converted back into train_generator using class_indices

```
# Convert the predict category back into train_generator.class_indices
label_map = dict((v,k) for k,v in train_generator.class_indices.items())
validate_df['prediction'] = validate_df['prediction'].replace(label_map)
```